# How to conditionally move the list element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below html and the unique identifier for this html is the `span` text `Reports`

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-heading">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <use xlink:href="#doc"></use>
        </svg><span class="menu-heading-title">Reports</span></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Doors report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=1">Doors report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Walls Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=2">Walls Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Windows Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=3">Windows Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Tables Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=4">Tables Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Chairs Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=5">Chairs Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the above html I always want the `Doors report` to show above the `Tables Report` if it exists otherwise `Tables Report` should be the last one

Below is the desired html if `Tables Report` exists

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-heading">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <use xlink:href="#doc"></use>
        </svg><span class="menu-heading-title">Reports</span></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Walls Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=2">Walls Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Windows Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=3">Windows Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Doors report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=1">Doors report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Tables Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=4">Tables Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Chairs Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=5">Chairs Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below is the desired html if `Tables Report` does not exists

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-heading">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <use xlink:href="#doc"></use>
        </svg><span class="menu-heading-title">Reports</span></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Walls Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=2">Walls Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Windows Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=3">Windows Report</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a title="Doors report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=1">Doors report</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can someone please help me to make it work with jQuery?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**:

```js
const spanText = 'Reports'
const tablesReportText = 'Tables Report'
const doorsReportText = 'Doors report'

const $myList = $('ul > *:contains(${spanText})').parent();

const $tablesReport = $myList.find('li a:contains(${tablesReportText})')

// if exists element with tablesReportText then will insert before it
if ($tablesReport[0]) {
  const $doorsReport = $myList.find('li a:contains(${doorsReportText})')
  $doorsReport.parent().insertBefore($tablesReport.parent())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-heading">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use xlink:href="#doc"></use></svg>
      <span class="menu-heading-title">Reports</span>
  </li> 
  <li class="menu-link"><a title="Doors report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=1">Doors report</a></li>
  <li class="menu-link"><a title="Walls Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=2">Walls Report</a></li>
  <li class="menu-link"><a title="Windows Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=3">Windows Report</a></li>
  <li class="menu-link"><a title="Tables Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=4">Tables Report</a></li>
  <li class="menu-link"><a title="Chairs Report" class="" href="/Reports/show.do?id=5">Chairs Report</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The HTML can not be modified, hence the `ul` tag can not be given `id`, can it be done without modifying the source html?

Comment: tried running your code but its not giving the desired output

Comment: you have changed the [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) by `single quotes`

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo the backticks `\`` in RanPaul's answer are deliberate - they are template strings in ES6 - try changing them back from `'` to `\``

Answer (score 0):

Make the tables report existing state the default. Then put a class of `no-tables` or something on the `<ul>`. Then use css to hide the tables and chairs report for the no-tables class. Something like:

```
.no-tables {
   #tables-report { display: none; } /* this id needs to exist on that report li */
   #chairs-report { display: none; } /* this id needs to exist on that report li */
}
```

Then use the following jQuery to remove that class and show tables and chair if that report exists:

```
if ($('#tables-report').length > 0) {
    $('ul').removeClass('no-tables');
}
```

To move the doors report, I'd do something like this:

```
if $('#doors-report').length > 0) {
   $('#doors-report').before($('#walls-report'));
}
```

The ID's above are just examples as they don't exist. You'll need some selector to identify all the working parts. All that said, the reports may be coming in/updated dynamically and that may make some of this not work, but hopefully this helps.